# Cannot call more than 100 INSERT queries

Tags: php, mysqli

I have to insert 1000 records to read from file and insert to db but my code is not working more than 100 times. It says `internal server 500` but it works fine when I run code below 100 times.  Are there any settings that I have to apply to insert more than 100 records?

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
    $servername = "**";
    $username = "**";
    $password = "**"; 
    $dbname = "**";

    $con=mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);

    for($i=0; $i<400; $i++){

        $query = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3)
                                    VALUES (value1, value2, value3)");          
    }

    $query->close();
    $con->close();
?>
```

It's working only 100 times.  If I set loop to run more than than that, it does not work any ideas?

Comment: is it produces any error?

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you cannot miss or ignore.

Comment: Actually that code would not load 1 row. Please add query you are really using. _We cannot debug pseudo code unless you want pseudo answers_

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: i think try using
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);     //300 seconds = 5 minutes

place it above your script and try again.

Comment: @manoj.kadlag it says only internal server 500 but it works fine when we run code below 100 time

Comment: @RiggsFolly it still showing me internal server error 500

Comment: **Why** is this the first time you mention that you are getting a **500 error**

Comment: @RiggsFolly if make loop to run 99 times then it works fine but more than 100 times

Comment: Where are you running this code. Local server or a cheap hosting server

Comment: @RiggsFolly Godaddy Shared hosting server

Comment: Added relevant comment information to post and improved English.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if this will eliminate your issue, but it is always better to try to reduce total database calls in your code.

Since you are INSERTing on the same table, you can do everything in a single query.  Build your single query inside the loop and then use `mysqli_query()` only once after the loop is finished.

Code:

```
$values="";
for($i=0; $i<400; $i++){
    $values.=($i==0?"",",")."('value1','value2','value3')";
}
$query=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3) VALUES $values;
```

Comment: @NiteshSharma If this solves your issue you can award my answer the green tick, but I can't really explain what kind of configuration would break once hitting 100 queries.  If you're still experiencing technical difficulties, leave a comment and/or update your question.

Answer (score 0):

Take care )

```
function interpolate($message, array $context = [], $openTag = '{', $closeTag = '}')
{
    // build a replacement array with braces around the context keys
    $replace = array();
    foreach ($context as $key => $val) {
        // check that the value can be casted to string
        if (!is_array($val) && (!is_object($val) || method_exists($val, '__toString'))) {
            $replace[$openTag . $key . $closeTag] = $val;
        }
    }

    // interpolate replacement values into the message and return
    return strtr($message, $replace);
}

function interpolatedQuery($conn, $query, array $context = [])
{
    $sql = interpolate($query, $context);
    $result = mysqli_query($sql);
    if (!$result && mysqli_connect_errno() && in_array(mysqli_connect_errno(), [1213, 1614])) {
        // deadlock
        usleep(50000);
        return interpolatedQuery($conn, $query, array $context);
    }
    return $result;
}

$values = [];
foreach ($records as $record) {
    $values[] = interpolate(
        '({value1}, {value2}, {value3})',
        [
            'value1' => $record['id'],
            'value2' => '"' . mysqli_real_escape_string($record['name']) . '"',
            'value3' => 'NULL'
        ]
    );
}

if (count($values)) {
    $chunks = array_chunk($values, 1000);
    foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
        interpolatedQuery(
            'INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3) VALUES{values}',
            [
                'values' => implode(', ', $chunk)
            ]
        );
    }
}
```